# Handle more listeners on the same event

Tags: codenameone

This question is referred to Codename One.

What does it happen if there are multiple listeners  on the same event? Is the execution predictable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

- They fire from the first added to the last added listener
- Always on the EDT
- If one of the listeners invokes `ActionEvent.consume()` execution stops

There is one big caveat. If one of the listeners invokes an `invokeAndBlock` call e.g. `addToQueueAndWait` or show `Dialog` etc. execution will stop until the invoke and block is freed and resume after...

That's why if you use a blocking call you should either:

- Use call serially
- Consume the event

Comment: Is the `EventDispatcher` called implicitly every time that we add a `Listener` using the Codename One API? Are there circumstances in which we need to use the `EventDispatcher`explicitly?

Comment: If you consume() the loop within the specific event dispatcher will stop. The thing is that one event can trigger many separate events, some of them will be impacted but some won't. E.g. a pointer release will trigger: pointer release on form (events and callbacks), pointer release on focused component, if it's a button or text area an action event on that etc. If you consume the pointerReleased event you will block the action event from occurring down the chain so the behavior should be pretty predictable. However, as this is still nuanced behavior there are always edge cases.